# cloning a .vdi file using virt-clone

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, virt-manager

I'm trying to clone .vdi file on ubuntu 18.04  using the following command

```
virt-clone --auto-clone -o "/home/simon/VirtualBox VMs/Win7_E5570/Win7_E5570.vdi" -n tmp.vdi
```

and am getting this error

```
ERROR    Domain '/home/simon/VirtualBox VMs/Win7_E5570/Win7_E5570.vdi' was not found.
```

But the file .vdi exists

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 simon simon 26703036416 Sep  8 08:52 '/home/simon/VirtualBox VMs/Win7_E5570/Win7_E5570.vdi'*
```

Could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: You should be using the `VBoxManage clonemedium` command: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/E97727/html/vboxmanage-clonevdi.html

Comment: Works like a charm, so easy when you know how